# Function norm proof using two-norm

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that $||f + g|| ≤ || f || + || g ||$ holds for the two-norm function norm.

Two-norm: $||f||_2 = (\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx)^{1/2}$

$||f||_2 = (\int_a^b (f(x) + g(x))^2 dx)^{1/2}$

$||f||_2 = (\int_a^b (f(x)^2 + 2f(x)g(x) + g(x)^2) dx)^{1/2}$

I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\|f+g\|^2
&= \int |f+g|^2
\\
&\le \int |f||f+g| + \int |g||f+g|
\\
&\le \|f\|\|f+g\| + \|g\| \|f+g\| & \text{Cauchy-Schwarz}
\\
&= (\|f\|+\|g\|)\|f+g\|.
\end{align}